# rsync keep overriding owner and group

Tags: rsync

The source file has the following permission `jim:jim`

The original target file has the following permission `www-data:www-data`

My command: `rsync -Pav --no-p --no-o --no-g file ubuntu@ip_address:/path/file`

And yet the target file becomes: `ubuntu:ubuntu`, i'd like to preseve it as `www-data:www-data`

The permission however is kept preserved eventhough the source and target file differs. What could be the problem?

**Note**: The rsync is done from MacOS to Ubuntu. Not sure if this has anything related.

Thank you.

Comment: What uids do the users have? With what user do you start rsync? Note that users in rsync are just uids, the transformation is done with the users a system has. Also keep in mind, that you might not have the rights to change the uid to someone else.

Comment: rsync initiated from macos with the user `jim`, the ssh that's used in rsync is under user `ubuntu`. i'm not trying to change the ownership of the target file though, trying to ignore it from being changed.

Answer (score 1):

Your target user account `ubuntu` does not have the rights to create a file owned by `www-data`, so it cannot achieve what you want.

Either use a target username of `www-data` or `root`, or if this is just for backups consider adding `-M--fake-super` to the command.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to preserve `www-data:www-data`, yet you specify `--no-o --no-g` which turns this off:

```
   --owner, -o
          This option causes rsync to set the owner of the destination file to 
          be the same as the source file, but only if the receiving rsync is  
          being  run  as the super-user (see also the --super and --fake-super
          options).  Without this option, the owner of new and/or transferred 
          files are set to the invoking user on the receiving side.
```

(same for group)

To get this to work you also need to be root on the remote host, you can do this with (if you have `sudo` on the remote machine with `NOPASSWD`):

```
rsync -Pav --rsync-path="sudo rsync" file ubuntu@ip_address:/path/file
```

Comment: omitting `--no-p --no-o --no-g` messes up even further. permissions are also overwritten. and all the files become `root:root` ownership.

Comment: If all the files should belong to www-data try `--no-o --no-g --rsync-path="sudo -u www-data rsync"`